# Extension of a Java application with new customer’s specific classes?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, packaging, ear

We have built a Java EE application targeting communication service providers. The application does all kind of calculations for them. 
We’d like to keep the application as flexible as possible, allowing the client to add new types of calculation themselves if they need it.

To execute the calculations, the core application has an **abstract class**: “**AbstractCalculation**”, with methods like “calculate” etc. This abstract class is used everywhere in the code.

```
@Entity
@Table “ALGO”
abstract class AbstractCalculation
(…)
```

Next of that, there are **core concrete classes** that extend this AbstractCalculation class. Those classes are also **JPA Entities** (a simply query can return all classes that should be considered for calculations)

```
@Entity
@Table “ALGO_ONE”
class CalculateAlgorithmOne extends AbstractCalculation
(…)

@Entity
@Table “ALGO_TWO”
class CalculateAlgorithmTwo extends AbstractCalculation
(…)
```

And of course, those classes are defined in the application **persistence.xml**:

```
Mypackage.CalculateAlgorithmOne
Mypackage.CalculateAlgorithmTwo
```

The application is packaged as an **EAR file**.

Let’s imagine that a customer want to introduce a its **own third type of calculation** which does not exist yet in the code 
e.g.

```
MyCustomerCalculateAlgorithThree.
```

Let’s suppose that this class is only relevant for that customer and should not be delivered to other customers.

1/ We, as software vendor, could include this new class and generate a specific EAR file for that customer; the other customer will still have the EAR file without that new class.
This is still manageable as we don’t target many customers (this is a very specialized application for large customers).

2/ Is there a way to include this customer class without changing the EAR file ? Ideally we shouldn’t even be aware of that new class (apart maybe for investigation/support purpose)
I guess that this is not possible (all classes must be part of the same EAR)?

3/ Do you have any other suggestion/best practice regarding how customer can add their own classes to a third-party application?

Thank in advance for your feedback

Best regards,

John

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. Use well-defined API. The API can be anything. You can use REST API and microservices, you can use EJBs and lookup....

Comment: Thanks - 
For REST API: how should the application "discover" the customer's specific API according to you ?